# Complete a formal proof of ~(~A&~B) from A in as few lines as possible

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

Prove ~(~A&~B) from A in as few lines as possible.

~ = negation
& = conjunction
v = disjunction
| = line in a subproof

Here's what I have:

1. A          - Premise
2. |~A        - Assume
3. |~B        - Assume
4. |~A&~B     - &Intro;3.4
5. ~(~A&~B)   - ~Intro;4

I'm quite sure this is wrong but I don't know how to fix it. Any help, even advice or tips, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have not discharged the two additional assumptions 2 and 3.

Comment: You have to start with premise **A** and with assumption **(~A&~B)**.

Comment: I'm confused by how you can assume ~A when you have A as a premise.  Also, don't you want to distribute ~ into the bracket?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Distributivity   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: @puppetsock You may assume anything you wish for the sake of an argument. However, it is not *useful* to assume ~A.

Comment: If the answer below is enough for you, please accept it and we can "close" the post.

Comment: What rules of inference are you allowed to use for your homework? Every textbook, and every professor, differ in which rules they allow students to use and which rules they don't allow students to use.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Your subproof is drawkcab.  You are not aiming to derive a position from a random assumption.

Negation introduction works by *deriving a contradiction* when assuming a position (`~A & ~B`), and thusly inferring its negation (`~(~A & ~B)`) holds when that assumption is discharged.

And so ...

```
  |_ A            premise
  |  |_ ~A & ~B   assumption
  |  |  :         :
  |  |  #         ~ elimination
  |  ~(~A & ~B)   ~ introduction
```